# Avoiding implicit precompiled header dependencies?

Tags: visual-c++, dependencies, precompiled-headers

We are using a precompiled header to include library files such as Boost and Windows.
Our `precompiled.h` is included explicitly at the top of each `.cpp` file in order to work with the precompiled header commands ([`/Yc`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7zc28563%28v=VS.90%29.aspx), [`/Yu`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z0atkd6c%28v=VS.90%29.aspx), and [`/Fp`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8f7a897x%28v=VS.90%29.aspx)).  I accepted that as necessary.

Recently, however, I found [`/FI`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8c5ztk84%28v=VS.90%29.aspx), which forces an include file at the top of the source file.  I tried using it to force-include `precompiled.h` instead of including it explicitly, and sure enough, it worked.
This would allow us to omit the precompiled header (which is an implementation detail, as far as I am concerned), and only specify the actual dependencies of the file.

Unfortunately, it looks like the only way to validate that we aren't relying on implicit dependencies provided by `precompiled.h` is to periodically run through a build without `/FI"precompiled.h"` to see which files have a problem.
This is fairly onerous.  Is there a better way?

Comment: While researching this question, I found a blog post that used  [`/FI` for precompiled headers](http://cheind.wordpress.com/2010/02/21/reducing-compilation-time-precompiled-header/), but there's no mention of dependency checking.

Comment: I think the answer is No but will be happy if anyone proves me wrong.

Comment: If our unit tests don't use the precompiled header, they would be the canary.  That's probably the right answer, but not all of our code is unit tested.